# Datatable to Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I will be improving my question as to how to populate a datagridview. Below is my code used in displaying the data filtered from an access database.

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    .dgCTraining.Rows.Add()
    With frmPersonalTraining.dgCTraining.Rows(frmPersonalTraining.dgCTraining.Rows.Count - 1)
        .Cells("cTraining").Value = dr("TrainingType")
        .Cells("cCourse").Value = dr("Condensed")
    End With
Next
```

The code above is displaying also the column names from the access table. How would display the results only from the database since my datagridview already has its own column names

Comment: Well, this site is not the best one to get tutorials. We answer to precise question involving programming code. Your question is too broad for Q&A site. Search some tutorial on line and, before posting the next question, please be sure to read the [help] and [ask]

Comment: Apologies. This is noted Steve. I've also resolved this question. I've used Datagridview's Rows.Count and it works for me :)